# VeraCrypt incorrect permissions?

Tags: encryption, veracrypt

My VeraCrypt is giving me an error every time I start the app but it runs.
How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you moved the file and/or changed the drive's (or partition or folder) permissions?

Comment: I restored from a back up drive using grsync. uninstalled/reinstalled but I am getting the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Quit VeraCrypt and delete the .VeraCrypt-Lock-Username file.
Start VeraCrypt and it will automatically create a new file with correct permissions.